# JSON parse error while parsing text

Tags: ajax, json

Hi I am getting a json object as this.

```
{"messages":["operator  will assit you"]}
```

I am getting **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character**
 I am using $.parseJSON(json);

I couldn't identify any syntax error in this.

Comment: Seems a problem of encoding. The ¿name? of the operator isn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Farmer was right. The object is already in parsed state.

i just used
          `object.messages`
and it worked like charm

Comment: Be sure to mark correct answer and close question. You should add this information as an edit instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting your code snippet would be helpful. I would guess you aren't parsing the string you are parsing the already parsed out object. You need to do one of the following:

```
var json = {"messages":["operator  will assit you"]};
```

or

```
var json = '{"messages":["operator  will assit you"]}';
$.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: Of course, if you already have the object, you wouldn't want or need to call `parseJSON`.